# MVC webapp with Azure AD authentication works fine in local but not when porting to Azure app services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have created web app by following below steps to implement the Azure active directory authentication(Work or school account authentication) to my Mvc webapp.

When I create the project in MVC web app itself it asks authentication mode of the project . So that I have changed the authenticate mode to Work or School account authentication. After checking this, it populates directory by default and I have checked the Read directory data.

After clicking create, the visual studio itself generates the following file for Work or school account authentication I beleive,

1. Startup.Auth.cs in app_start folder
2. AdalTokenCache.cs, ApplicationDbContext in Moldels folder

Once I run the app from visual studio it works fine that as usual it goes to Microsft online page and if it succeeds the authentication it came to the home controller of the web app.

To check with azure app service, we have created the web app in Azure webservices and copied the code base to mentioed remote folder by FTP client. But now it gots the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er0CD.png) like screen shot.

**(Ps : I'm using App Service plan/pricing tier as FREE TIER also not adding the SSL Certificates to my web app)**

Comment: Your code is not able to connect to the database server while running data base creation code. Are using entity framework? Can you check the connection string of database used by the application? Is it still pointing to local db when deployed on azure?

Comment: Your primary problem is that it can't connect to a database. It's not an Azure AD authentication problem.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya When i working with the local environment it works perfectly ( Via the connection String :connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=;Initial Catalog=aspnet-xxx-20170630011929;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" / )

Yes i deployed whole my project in Azure Including the .mdf files.So obviously my connection string will be same as the above.(after the azure deployment) 

I new in this process Could you tell what will a entity framework role in the connection process ?

Comment: @juunas In doubt that in Azure App Services already/default any (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB (or) .\SQLEXPRESS Available ?

Since i've used the attachement of the .mdf file from localdb\mssqllocaldb.It works perfectly in my local machine.

Because i've already installed sqlexpress in my local.So i can able to connect the localdb for accessing the .mdf files.So that i'm asking about is there any build in app-Services(localdb/splexpress) in Azure ?

Comment: If you are deploying on azure webrole it doesn't come with sqlexpress installed on it not you can install on it. You might want to use sql azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chetan said , you can't use localdb/sqlexpress with Azure app service. You could use SQL Azure , or  you could [connect to on-premises SQL Server from a web app in Azure App Service using Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server)

Comment: Yes I have changed the connection string that pointing to Azure sql server then its working fine